# Redirecting a php submit form

Tags: php

In the following php script Dreamweaver is giving me a syntax error every time I add the redirect header:

```
header('Location: thankyou.htm');
```

The info is sent to my email address with no problem but the client is not redirected to the thankyou.htm page. Does not matter whether or not I enter the full url.  Sincerely appreciate any help.  Please keep explanation simple - THANK YOU!!

PLEASE SEE BELOW...

```
<?php

$senderName = $_POST['name'];
$senderEmail =  $_POST['email'];
$sendToEmail = "wildlifeart@heathersoos.ca";
$emailMessage = $_POST['message'];

$recipient = "$sendToEmail";

$headers = "From: $senderEmail ";
$message = "From: $senderName, \nEmail Address: $senderEmail\nMessage: $emailMessage";
$message = StripSlashes($message);

mail($recipient, "Heather's Artwork", $message, $headers)

header('Location: thankyou.htm');


?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a semicolon after the `mail` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon (`;`) at

```
mail($recipient, "Heather's Artwork", $message, $headers); <-- here
```

Comment: THANKS so much for your help.  How did I miss that? Appreciate the quick response!! Take care!

Comment: You can thank me by accepting my answer by clicking on the V sign on the top left :) thanks!